# is there something wrong with this JavaScript if statement?

Tags: javascript

I've got this small bit of JS code which I'm sure was working but seems to have stopped:

```
if(currentUser && currentUser._id === shinyItem.author.id || currentUser && currentUser.isAdmin) {
 <p>Hello banana</p>
}
```

The problem seems to be this part:

```
currentUser._id === shinyItem.author.id
```

If I console.log both those values are the same, so it should be working. However, if I remove it and run this code it works just fine:

```
if(currentUser || currentUser && currentUser.isAdmin) {
  <p>Hello banana</p>
}
```

It's probably something painfully obvious, any help appreciated.

Comment: "those values are the same" well, they are probably not.

Comment: Please use `()` when you mix `&&` and `||`. The order of execution can be confusing when you look at this code.

Comment: Can you ensure type of those values? Like are both of type ObjectId or string?

Comment: Please add the shinyItem and currentUser objects. Need to know whats inside. Adding a code snippet would be much appreciable to fix the issue. Also have you tried without checking the type ? means '==' instead of  '==='

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer. I though if I use only == it would sort it but that also results in falsey so it still didn't work.

I then did some more digging and found this post stackoverflow.com/questions/11637353/… which seems to solve my problem. What I didn't understand was that the contents of currentUser._id is a custom mongoDB object ID type. To resolve I needed to use the mongodb function .equals() like this:

```
if(currentUser && currentUser._id.equals(shinyItem.author.id) || currentUser && currentUser.isAdmin) {
```

Answer (score 2):

If `currentUser.isAdmin` is falsey, but `currentUser._id` looks to log the same thing as `shinyItem.author.id`, it must be that they aren't actually the same value. Either the type of one is different from the other (such as if one is of type `string` and the other is of type `number`), or the difference can't be easily seen visually, such as if one has a trailing space or few, or has a similar-looking character (eg `1` the number and `l` the letter), or one may have a zero-width character that the other lacks, or something like that.

Double check the values in both variables. It's clear that *something* is different between them. If both are strings and you still don't see a difference, you can examine the character code of each index of the string to find the difference eg:

```js
const str1 = 'foo\u200bbar';
const str2 = 'foobar';
console.log(str1);
console.log(str2);
// They look the same when logged, but...
for (let i = 0; i < str1.length; i++) {
  if (str1[i] !== str2[i]) {
    console.log(`Found difference at index ${i}: code ${str1[i].charCodeAt()} !== code ${str2[i].charCodeAt()}`);
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just because they log the same value doesn't mean they're of the same type.

You're using the [strict equality operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness#Strict_equality_using) (`===`) and values of differing type will be considered unequal.

You can try using the [loose equality operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness#Loose_equality_using) (`==`) to see if you get your expected result. Alternatively, you can perform explicit type conversion to ensure you're dealing with matching types.

To illustrate:

```js
numberValue = 12345;
stringValue = '12345';

console.log('numberValue: ' + numberValue);
console.log('stringValue: ' + stringValue);
console.log('typeof numberValue: ' + (typeof numberValue));
console.log('typeof stringValue: ' + (typeof stringValue));
console.log('numberValue === stringValue: ' + (numberValue === stringValue));
console.log('numberValue == stringValue: ' + (numberValue == stringValue));
console.log('numberValue === parseInt(stringValue, 10): ' + (numberValue === parseInt(stringValue, 10)));
```

---

Also, a simpler way to express your conditional statement would be:

```
if (currentUser && (currentUser._id === shinyItem.author.id || currentUser.isAdmin)) {
```

Comment: This is better, you don't have to check currentUser twice.

Answer (score 1):

Add parentheses.

```js
if ((currentUser && (currentUser._id === shinyItem.author.id)) || (currentUser && currentUser.isAdmin)) {
  return <p>Hello banana</p>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*Strict comparison* `===` means that both type and value must be the same to return `true` as result. The reason, both those `currentUser._id` and `shinyItem.author.id` look the same, is that they might be used in a context, where javascript engine tries to implement *type coercion*. If `currentUser._id` is mongoose `ObjectID`, it has `toString` method in it, and javascript engine will use it while implementing *type coercion* and returns a `string`:

```
// log id is 5e59d4dfe93451416fc551db, instead of 
// log id is ObjectID {_bsontype: "ObjectID", id: Buffer(12)}
console.log(`id is ${currentUser._id}`);
```

So using strict comparison between `ObjectID` and `string` resolves to `false`:

```
// value is the     value is the 
// same, but type   same, but type 
// is ObjectID      is string
currentUser._id === shinyItem.author.id // false
```

But loose equality comparison `==` resolves to `true`, because, behind the scene, javascript engine tries to coerce both values to the same type (`string`), using `toString` method of `ObjectID` and converting it to the `string`:

```
currentUser._id == shinyItem.author.id // true
```

Mongoose also has [id virtual getter](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#id), which returns the documents _id field cast to a string, so you can use it like this (if you did not disable it in schema):

```
// id is a string
currentUser.id === shinyItem.author.id // true
```